# Creating colored QR codes using zxing

Tags: colors, qr-code, zxing

I am using the google open source java zxing creator: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

to create QR codes. I have everything in place and working (I'm loading the java files using coldfusion and writing the image to the browser.)

What I want now is to change the black QR colour to something else. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Would I need to edit a decompiled version of the encoder java file? Or is there a way I could add a color argument to the encoding routine?

Thanks
Shaun

Comment: did you find a solution? i need excatly the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `MatrixToImageWriter.java` (which I assume you are using), under `javase/` change the constant `BLACK`. It is an `int` in ARGB format and currently has value `0xFF000000`. Leave the alpha value at `0xFF`. Change the rest to describe your color in hex format. You can do the same with `WHITE` if you like.

Comment: Yes, I am using the 'com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter' java file. I've downloaded a pre compiled version, but I guess I can get a source file from here: (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout) and edit it to recompile the file with a custom colour. Is that what you would do?

Answer (score 4):

Try this ::

```
BitMatrix matrix = new QRCodeWriter().encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, this.width, this.height, getEncodeHints());
/*
Here the config object represents the QR Code colors.
i.e. Brown and White respectively
*/ 
MatrixToImageConfig conf = new MatrixToImageConfig(-10223615,-1);
BufferedImage qrcode = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(matrix, conf);
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're generating qr code like below:

```
QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(code,null,
                                                Contents.Type.TEXT,
                                                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(),            
                                                yourDimension);
```

Your output's dimension will be based on your code. Set your dimension as possible as low. So you can find exact positions of qr code place you want to change color.

Than get your pixels from bitmap with:

```
int[] allpixels = new int[bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getWidth()];
bitmap.getPixels(allpixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

And color pixels you want:

```
for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++) {
     allpixels[i] = Color.Red; // your rgb color
      }
```

Convert dp to px for every devices:

```
qrCodeDimension = dpToPx((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.qr_dimen));

public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
      return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
   }
```

Finaly set your colored pixels to bitmap:

```
bitmap.setPixels(allpixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, qrCodeDimension, qrCodeDimension, false);
```

This's how i solved the problem. I hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using this code to print your qr code image :

```
    QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path);
```

You can specify your own config file (MatrixToImageConfig) and pass it along to MatrixToImageWriter like this :

```
    QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
    int onColor = 0xFF000000;
    int offColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    MatrixToImageConfig matrixToImageConfig = new MatrixToImageConfig(onColor, offColor);
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path, matrixToImageConfig);
```

You can pass your colors in onColor and offColor, which are integers. Append your color code to "0xFF" in onColor and offColor variable and you are good to go.
Cheers.