# Styling/Coloring the generated QR code

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

hi i'm using this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-qr-codes-java-servlet-qr-code-java/ as my reference in generating QR images.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from("Hello World").to(ImageType.PNG).stream();
```

the default color of the QR image is black, is there any way to change its color?

i have also found this question [Creating colored QR codes using zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723588/creating-colored-qr-codes-using-zxing) but i'm quite confused on the answer.

Comment: does the problems solved ?

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is a picture, you can easily modified the color on it. But the QR code should remain black to have 100% cover with devices that will be reading it. Is part of they specification ISO/IEC 18004.

Comment: yes, i get a picture but i dont know how to modify or fill the black square matrix to my desired color. i'm pretty sure that QR codes can be multicolored and black is not a must. reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/zxing/lmaHvo2sYq0 rather than displaying a black qr image on my browser, i want it something to be blue or other color. is there any way to do this?

Comment: A one way to this is using [RGBImageFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/RGBImageFilter.html).

Comment: im sorry but im not quite sure how to do this. as my code above i get a `ByteArrayOutputStream`